# Discord Bot Command log

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I have a Discord Bot where I am trying to track the usage of the bot by tracking command usage. The code I have is below. I am running into the problem where I cant seem to get the command name.
Here is the code:

```
    @commands.Cog.listener(name='on_command')
    async def print(self, ctx, command):
        server = ctx.guild.name
        user = command.author
        command = ctx.command
        print(f'{server} > {user} > {command}')
```

When running a command (any command) it says "missing required arg 'command'" I have also tried other code. The other code I have tried:

```
    @commands.Cog.listener(name='on_command')
    async def print(self, command, server=None, user=None):
        server = command.guild.name
        user = command.author
        print(f'{server} > {user} > {command}')
```

This just sends everything except for the command. In place of the command is sends a hex code looking thing (0x____). What am I missing? What can I try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> When running a command (any command) it says "missing required arg 'command'"

You're getting this error because the [API documentation for on_command](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=on_command#discord.on_command) states that it only has 1 parameter, being `ctx`, so Discord will *never* pass anything else into it, so your `command` parameter will always be missing.

The docs for [`Context`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=on_command#discord.ext.commands.Context) say you can get the command using `ctx.command`.

```
@commands.Cog.listener(name='on_command')
async def print(self, ctx):
    server = ctx.guild.name
    user = ctx.author
    command = ctx.command
    print(f'{server} > {user} > {command}')
```

> In place of the command is sends a hex code looking thing (0x____)

That's the string representation of a `Context` instance. As you're only sending `command` and you're doing nothing with it, and seeing as it's actually `Context` instead of a `Command` as I explained above, this will be what comes out.

Comment: I tried this, but it wasn't called on command. I will try to investigate further to critique more helpfully

Answer (score 0):

I wanted something similar and got to this through trial and error, where msg_dump_channel is the id of the channel you want to print your output to.

```
from discord.ext import commands
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '>')
@bot.event
async def on_command(ctx):
    channel = bot.get_channel(msg_dump_channel)
    server = ctx.guild.name
    user = ctx.author
    command = ctx.command
await channel.send('{} used {} in {}'.format(user, command, server))
```